# Vertical alignment of tabularx row

Tags: tables, tabularx

I am having trouble vertically aligning the first column. Could you suggest any other way to make this table look attractive? I would appreciate it.

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\usepackage{cite}
\ifCLASSINFOpdf
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\else
\fi
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{array}
\ifCLASSOPTIONcompsoc
\usepackage[caption=false,font=normalsize,labelfont=sf,textfont=sf]{subfig}
\else
\usepackage[caption=false,font=footnotesize]{subfig}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{stfloats}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table*}[t]
        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25}
        \centering % default value: 6pt
        \caption{Comparison of Algorithm Results}\label{tab_com}

        \begin{tabularx}{0.8\linewidth}{ 
                @{\hspace{0em}} >{\hsize=0.3\hsize}L    
                @{\hspace{-7em}} >{\hsize=0.3\hsize}L
                @{\hspace{-5em}} >{\hsize=0.3\hsize}L
                @{\hspace{1em}} >{\hsize=0.3\hsize}L
                @{\hspace{0em}} >{\hsize=0.5\hsize}L }
            \toprule
            %% disable left-hand padding in first cell via "@{}" particle
            \centering\arraybackslash\hspace{-2em}\textbf{} & \textbf{Capacitor} & \textbf{Trimming} & \textbf{Servo}\\
            \midrule
            
            \vspace{0em}\hspace{1em} \textbf{Strength} & \parbox[t]{0.2\textwidth}{%
                \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=1em,itemsep=0.5pt,parsep=0pt]\raggedright%
                    \item Simplicity
                    \item Cost-effectiveness
                    
            \end{itemize}} &\parbox[t]{0.25\textwidth}{%
                \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=1em,itemsep=0.5pt,parsep=0pt]\raggedright%
                    
                    \item Ease of implementation
                    \item Time-efficient
                    
            \end{itemize}}&\parbox[t]{0.25\textwidth}{%
                \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=1em,itemsep=0.5pt,parsep=0pt]\raggedright%
                    \item An offset of low DC is possible
                    \item The DC offset is actively removed
                    \item Adjustable low-frequency roll-off
            \end{itemize}}  \\
            
            \vspace{0em}\hspace{1em} \textbf{Weakness}  &  \parbox[t]{0.2\textwidth}{%
                \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=1em,itemsep=0.5pt,parsep=0pt]\raggedright%
                    \item Time-consuming                    \item big and bulky
            \end{itemize}} & \parbox[t]{0.25\textwidth}{%
                \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=1em,itemsep=0.5pt,parsep=0pt]\raggedright%
                    \item During operation Adjustments
                    \item Accumulated DCs Offsett
            \end{itemize}} & \parbox[t]{0.25\textwidth}{%
                \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=1em,itemsep=0.5pt,parsep=0pt]\raggedright%
                    \item A supply rail system is needed
                    \item Power requirements
                    \item Must be carefully designed
                    
            \end{itemize}}\\
            
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabularx}
    \end{table*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{array, booktabs,tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\RaggedRight%
                       \hsize=#1\hsize%                 % <---
                       \linewidth=\hsize}X}             % <---
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[66]
    \begin{table*}[ht]
        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25}
        \centering 
        \caption{Comparison of Algorithm Results}
        \label{tab_com}

        \setlist[itemize]{nosep,
                          leftmargin = *,
                          label      = $\bullet$ ,
                          after=\end{minipage},                  % <---
                          before=\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth} % <---
                             }
        \begin{tabularx}{0.8\linewidth}{>{\bfseries}l 
                                        L{0.8}
                                        L{1} 
                                        L{1.2}
                                        }
            \toprule
            & \textbf{Capacitor} & \textbf{Trimming} & \textbf{Servo}\\
            \midrule
        Strength    &   \begin{itemize}
                    \item Simplicity
                    \item Cost-effectiveness
                        \end{itemize}
                        &   \begin{itemize}
                        \item Ease of implementation
                        \item Time-efficient
                            \end{itemize}
                            &   \begin{itemize}
                            \item An offset of low DC is possible
                            \item The DC offset is actively removed
                            \item Adjustable low-frequency roll-off
                                \end{itemize}       \\
        Weakness    &   \begin{itemize}
                    \item Time-consuming                    
                    \item big and bulky
                        \end{itemize}
                        &  \begin{itemize}
                        \item During operation Adjustments
                        \item Accumulated DCs Offsett
                            \end{itemize}
                            &  \begin{itemize}
                            \item A supply rail system is needed
                            \item Power requirements
                            \item Must be carefully designed
                                \end{itemize}       \\

            \bottomrule
        \end{tabularx}
    \end{table*}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:**

- Your table code is unnecessary complicated. Since you have all columns equal width, you can omit all settings of their widths.
- Use of `\parbox` inside columns is not consistent and not needed
- If you like to have different columns width where contents are lists (`itemize`), you need to redefine their width as follows: `{\hsize=#1\hsize\linewidth=\hsize}` or for more convenient writing of column specifications as is done in above MWE
- remove from your document preamble all of duplicates

**Addendum**
Your table can be fit in one column. For this I suggest

- reduce size of `\tabcolsep` (from default 6pt to for example 4pt)
- reduce font size to `\small`
- remove first and last space in table by inserting `@{}` at begin and end of column specification
- first column replace with row

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{array, booktabs,tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\RaggedRight%
                       \hsize=#1\hsize%                 % <---
                       \linewidth=\hsize}X}             % <---
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[66]
    \begin{table}[ht]
        \small
        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}
        \centering 
        \caption{Comparison of Algorithm Results}
        \label{tab_com}

        \setlist[itemize]{nosep,
                          leftmargin = *,
                          label      = $\bullet$ ,
                          after=\end{minipage},                  % <---
                          before=\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth} % <---
                             }
        \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
        \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} L{0.9}
                                            L{1}
                                            L{1.1}
                                        @{} }
            \toprule
        \textbf{Capacitor} & \textbf{Trimming} & \textbf{Servo}\\
            \midrule
        \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Strength:}}       \\
            \begin{itemize}
        \item Simplicity
        \item Cost-effectiveness
            \end{itemize}
            &   \begin{itemize}
            \item Ease of implementation
            \item Time-efficient
                \end{itemize}
                &   \begin{itemize}
                \item An offset of low DC is possible
                \item The DC offset is actively removed
                \item Adjustable low-frequency roll-off
                    \end{itemize}                   \\
            \midrule
        \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Weakness:}}      \\
            \begin{itemize}
        \item Time-consuming
        \item big and bulky
            \end{itemize}
            &  \begin{itemize}
            \item During operation Adjustments
            \item Accumulated DCs Offsett
                \end{itemize}
                &  \begin{itemize}
                \item A supply rail system is needed
                \item Power requirements
                \item Must be carefully designed
                    \end{itemize}       \\

            \bottomrule
        \end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]